# Random variable $X = U[1,3]$ , $T = X^2$

Tags: probability

I want to find the density function of T. 
This is my reasoning:
$$F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}(T \leq t)$$
$$ F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}( -\sqrt{t} \leq x \leq \sqrt{t} )$$
Then I find that $F_T(t) = \sqrt{t}$.

By deriving I find:
$$ f_T(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\mathbb{1}_{[1,9]}$$
However for it to be a density function I'd need a 4 instead of a 2. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started alright, with

$$F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}(T \leq t)$$
$$ F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}( -\sqrt{t} \leq x \leq \sqrt{t} )$$

But notice that $X$ follows a  $U[1,3]$ distribution, hence

$$ F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}( -\sqrt{t} \leq x \leq \sqrt{t} ) = \mathbb{P}(1 \leq x \leq \sqrt{t} )$$

Now because $[1,3]$ has length $2$, we have that the density function of $X$ is just $0.5$ and we get

$$ F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}(1 \leq x \leq \sqrt{t} ) = \frac{\sqrt{t}-1}{2}$$

Now if you derive it, you get to the correct result.

Comment: What a silly mistake, I need more coffe. Thank you!

Comment: Happens to the best! Yw